# populate dropdown in ribbon with folders from a specific site pages library only

Tags: 2010, javascript, ribbon

I already have created a dropdownlist in the ribbon, however I need to fill it with the folders inside the Site pages library for example.

I tried, but I didnt find any article or blog about it.

here is the code I have so far.

What I want is to put a move button, and when the user selects some html files, they will be able to move the files to the selected folder.

I found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407837.aspx. how to get a folder list, but I need a folder list of the site pages library only, NOT all folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render a javascript for the populate command that you specified in your XML on the same page. You can render it with custom webpart or delegate control for example.

**UPDATE**:
Although there is a bunch of methods to get all the folders from the library here's the one I've quickly tested for you in the Site Pages library:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.TryGetList("Site Pages");
List<SPFolder> allFolders = list.Folders.OfType<SPListItem>().Select(li => li.Folder).ToList();
```

And so all you need is to provide a function to `PopulateQueryCommand` See the example from Chris O'Brien [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/02/ribbon-customizations-dropdown-controls.html). Note the `getDropdownItemsXml` function used as the source of the data for PopulateQueryCommand. My additional advice for you is to not use a page component like in this example - this technique useful for really big Ribbon modifications. For your simple task the simple JS function is enough.

And finally - this is the one way to render population function on the page from the server side - I've created a web part code for this:

```
public class JSRenderWebPart : WebPart
    {
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("DropDownPopulateFunction", @"
                function PopulateDropDowm()
                {
                    // render your population logic here
                }
                ");

        }
    }
```

Comment: please see the edit, is it possible to fetch only the folders from a specific pagelibrary? Not all folders?

Comment: Do you need all the folders recursive or just at the root level or something else?

Comment: indeed, recursive.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I've added a function rendering example too. Ask if there's something unclear still.